# Vue.Js При нажатии на кнопу получить данные с инпута

Tags: vue.js, framework7

Ситуация такая есть такой вот код:

```
<f7-list form id="address-form">
  <!-- Textarea -->
  <f7-list-item>
  <f7-input type="textarea" placeholder="Default address" id="address"  v-model.text="address"></f7-input>
  </f7-list-item>
  </f7-list>
  <!-- Button Nex -->
  <f7-block>
  <f7-button class="" value="1" id="btnPageAdress" href="#" @click="getFormValues()">Next</f7-button>
  </f7-block>
```

Ну и скрипт

```
<script>
    export default {
    name: 'app',
      data() {
          return {
            address: ''
          }
        },
      methods: {
        getFormValues () {
            var sendAddess = this.address
            console.log(this.sendAddess)
        }
      }
        }
</script>
```

Не понимаю чего не работает. Может кто-то помочь.

ПС (Разобрался немного больше в ситуации, суть какая в инпут приходят данные при загрузке страницы, но загвоздка в том что если не будет активности(фокуса) по инпуту то данные не запушутся в переменную address. Я так понимаю нужен какой-то вотчер который будет отслеживать элемент или чекать каждые пол сек примерно. Но я ток начал работать с Vue и пока не представляю как это сделать)

Comment: Не очень понятно про "если не будет активности" - у вас адрес заранее чем-то должен быть заполнен или есть иной источник данных, помимо формы ввода, из которого адрес должен подтянуться до отображения формы? Vue автоматически поменяет данные, когда будет активность в поле ввода, так что вотчер не требуется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно ждать загрузки данных от компонента, то используй $emit в компоненте а $on в родителе. Более подробнее [https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Использование-v-on-с-пользовательскими-событиями](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-v-on-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8)

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      message: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getMessage () {
      alert(this.message)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="message">
  <button @click="getMessage">Получить данные</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
```